# Which correct permissions must have folders and files for website?

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, chmod

Which correct permissions must have folders and files for website? Also I need for `example.com/public/images` return forbidden but images inside it must be shown. And how can I do it automatically.

```
public (folder) 
   images (folder) (example.com/images/) must return 403
      image-1.png (file) (example.com/images/image-1.png ) user can view 
      image-2.png (file) (example.com/images/image-2.png ) user can view 
   css (folder) (example.com/css/) must return 403
      bootstrap (folder) (example.com/css/bootstrap) must return 403
         bootstrap.css (file) (example.com/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css) user can view
      custom.css (file)
   js (folder)
      bootstrap (folder)
         bootstrap.js (file)
      custom.js (file)
   assets (folder)
       ckeditor (folder)
          adapters (folder)
             jquery.js (file)
   index.php (file)
   .htaccess (file)
```

Comment: How would you define "correct permissions"? And what keeps you from setting them once?

Comment: I don know which one is correct 775, 750, 644. in **images** folder users can upload images but images folder must return forbidden message but they can also view files when full path is correct

Comment: How do you define "correct"? These three permission configurations have different meanings, any of them might be usable for some kind of context

Comment: I change the code, please check again

Comment: You haven't shared any code in your question. Also, what do you mean by "must return 403"? That's not related to permissions. Is there any good reason not to simply disable directory listings (`Options -Indexes`) without fiddling around with permissions?

Comment: 403 - it's http  code  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: Please share more details - why should any folder, directly called, return anything else than 403? Is this because you have enabled directory listings? If yes, what makes you think that any permission setting helps to avoid this - why not disable such listings instead?

Comment: for example sudo chmod -R 644 public/images/*

Comment: What's your question about that sudo call? Please edit your question to contain all relevant information - start with: why not disable directory listings? This would directly return 403, without any other configuration

Comment: I need add Options -Indexes  in my htaccess, thank you @NicoHaase

Comment: Note: "folders" is a Windows and user concept. On Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories". Folders are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Add Options -Indexes in htaccess